# How to debug JWT issue in .Net Framework AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jwt, okta

I have Asp.Net 4.6 webAPI application workking with JWT. I am using the [Okta authorization code flow](https://okta.github.io/authentication-guide/implementing-authentication/auth-code)/token exchange to get the token. I then use the token in all my requests. Everything works fine when using my Okta dev endpoint, but when I use our production Okta endpoint, authenticated requests fails. The authorization, and code/token exchange works fine, but when I request data to my WebApi controller with the [Authorize] attribute, the request doesn't seem to return anything, even an error. In fact the request in chrome shows that the request never finishes. (Though the preflight OPTIONS request does get a 200). I can also see the request in Wireshark, and that a response is never sent.

The most obvious answer is that there is something I have a configuration issue either in my code, or or on the production Okta endpoint which is causing the Authorize attribute to *silently* fail. But my main concern is that I can't seem to find a way to debug it. I tried inheriting from the Authorize attribute, and overriding all the methods to see if I can determine anything by putting breakpoints in those methods, but the methods OnAuthorization, IsAuthorized, HandleUnauthorizedRequest, etc seem to never get called.

1. Which is the best way to debug there? Is there an Asp.Net event I can hook into to see what is being sent/returned to Okta to validate the incoming token?
2. Why is it silently failing? This seems like an error that by design should bubble up.

Comment: If the request is authorizing that would seem to suggest that the token is valid and decrypted properly. I would check and make sure that the client is actually sending what you think it should in the claims. Hook up Fiddler or another HTTP proxy to capture the request capture the token and paste it into jwt.io to see what you get in the token data.

Comment: The request is not authorizing. The client authenticates via redirect to a hosted Okta page that authenticates the user and redirects back with a code, that can then be used to exchange for a token. I have verified that the token that comes back is fine. It is when the client tries to make a request to my backend which is using the Authorize attribute that the problem occurrs. I have used wireshark to look at the client request, and it does have the Bearer header and looks correct. I try pasting that token into jwt.io to verify it I guess. But it works fine with a the dev oka account, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most probably is because your production does not have API access management. In your preview org. you have API AM for free thus it works. In your production org. you gotta buy the feature. To test on each org. go to Okta admin dashboard > security > API. You might see "authorization servers" tab for one but not the other.

Another issue might be, if your issue is your Org. URL then Okta does not give out the key to the token cannot be verified locally.

it is hard to say without looking at your configuration but the above two scenarios are very common

Comment: Thank you.I will look into this and get back to you.

Comment: This was the case. We needed to purchase an add-on to validate the token.